# Add an empty column in WPF GridView

Tags: wpf, gridview

I have a ListView (GridView) bound to a collection. For aesthetic reason, I want an empty column at the beginning. If I do

```
<ListView.View>
    <GridView>
        <GridViewColumn Width="100" />
        <GridViewColumn Header="Col 1" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding P1}" />
        <GridViewColumn Header="Col 2" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding P2}" />
        <GridViewColumn Header="Col 3" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding P3}" />
    </GridView>
</ListView.View>
```

I get the .ToString() of the ItemSource in the first column. I just want an empty column, and I do not want to bind to an empty string property. Any idea?

I just hope it is not too obvious...

Comment: Wild guess `<GridViewColumn Width="100" DisplayMemberBinding="{x:Null}"/>`

Comment: Doesn't work. Fills the column with the .ToString() of the ItemSource

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Maybe use an empty `CellTemplate`?

```
    <GridViewColumn Width="100"> 
        <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
            <DataTemplate />
        </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
    </GridViewColumn>
```

Comment: Works! Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Even better than a `DataTemplate`, use `{x:Null}` as a binding.

```
<GridViewColumn Header="Empty Column" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Source={x:Null}}" />
```

Defining a `DataTemplate` is verbose and causes lagging when scrolling through a ListView with many items.

Answer (score -1):

Or just don't specify anything...

```
<GridViewColumn Header="Col 3" Width="500" />
```

Comment: That doesn't work. It fills the column with the .ToString() of the ItemSource